# How to fix CRC error when doing a SQL Server database backup?

Tags: sql-server

I'm in a pickle and any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm running our office's ERP Software (Acumatica) on a local server with Windows Server 2016 and SQL Server 2017.

Acumatica is currently running fine, we are not getting any errors whatsoever while using the app. We have 20+ employees constantly accessing Acumatica imputing data and so for. I have not receive any complains.

The problem that I'm having is that I'm getting an error when trying to backup the database using SQL Server Management Studio. When the backup process reaches 90% I get a SQL Server database cyclic redundancy check (CRC) error, and the backup fails.

I tried manually copying the `.MDF` and `.LDF` files to an external hard drive but the `.MDF` file fails just at the very end (99% with 120MB left to copy) with an error

> Cannot read from source

I was able to copy the `.LDF` file. The `.MDF` file is around 140 GB in size and the `.LDF` file 180 GB.

What can I do to fix this and be able to do a full backup?.. The latest successful backup that I have is from 3 weeks ago. I really need to be able to backup the data before this gets any worse.

I have been thinking about running chkdsk with the repair command but I'm afraid it will make it worse and loose the database and/or data.

Any advice would be very highly appreciated.

Regards.

Carlos

Comment: Why is your LDF so large? When was the last time you did a transaction log back up?

Comment: No idea why its so big. I have not done a Transaction Log Backup. I thought that when doing a full backup the transaction log gets backed up as well.

Comment: If you're never doing transaction log backups, the fact that your log file is so huge suggests it's in Full recovery mode. If you aren't doing transaction log back up, don't use the full database recovery model. If you are using it, then make sure you are doing transaction log backups regularly (like, every 15 minutes).

Comment: Just checked and I'm in Full Recovery Model. Can I recover the database from the LDF file?

Comment: The logs are useless without the database. But like I said, if you're in full recovery mode then you should be doing regular transaction log backups. The fact that you have never done one, and you're database's log file is 180GB is a huge waste of storage. Start backing up those logs, or stop using full recovery mode (and then shrink the log file).

Comment: Will do as soon as I get out of this mess. - In my test server I restored the backup that I have from 3 weeks ago. The files sizes of the .MDF and .LDF are about the same, if I copy the .LDF file from the production server is it possible to bring the database up to date?

Comment: You need to `RESTORE` the database, not copy the files. You can't copy a database file while it's online. I really suggest fixing your logs first, and then getting the database backup. I doubt that having 180GB of logs is helping the problem here.

Comment: Try this kinda old but still good discussion on [corruption](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/help-my-database-is-corrupt-now-what) by someone very knowledgeable.

Comment: @Larnu - is there a way to shutdown all database apps (but the one used for backup) so that the database can be fully backed up, similar to doing system image backups on WIndows? Note that some third party system image backup apps have the ability to restore files and folders from their backup images.

Comment: Backups can be done while the database is online, @rcgldr, and things like running DDL and DML statements against them won't stop them running. Have you fixed your transaction log problem yet?

Comment: `DBCC CHECKDB WITH PHYSICAL_ONLY` will tell you what is wrong, then you need to consider how to repair it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm having is that I'm getting an error when trying to backup the database

That's potentially bad.

> I have not done a Transaction Log Backup ... I'm in Full Recovery Model

That's actually good. Then [backup the log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/back-up-a-transaction-log-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).  Somewhere safe.

> In my test server I restored the backup that I have from 3 weeks ago

Almost home.  On your test server restore that old full with NORECOVERY, then restore the log backup.  If that works, your data is safe.  And even if your database is corrupt you can restore from the old full, the big log backup, and a [Tail Log backup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/tail-log-backups-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) from the production server.

Comment: Hi David Browne and @larnu thanks for all your advice and help. I was able to successfully create a backup of theTransaction Log of the production server database. So just to make sure, now the next step would be in my test server 1) Restore the full backup from 3 weeks ago with the NORECOVERY option and then Restore the Log Backup that I just made. With this two steps I should be good? or am I missing something else?

Comment: Yes.  That should create a good copy of your database as of the time of the log backup.  You can repeat with additional log backups as needed.  Using your test database you can rebuild your production server if necessary, after you determine if you have data corruption or storage system issues.

Comment: Great, thanks so much. I started the restoration process. Lets hope and everything goes smoothly. Quick question. While a wait, I was wondering the following: Is it possible to do a differential backup in the production server with the full backup that I have from 3 weeks ago?

Comment: Might work, but that copy is suspect so I wouldn’t recommend it if you have an alternative.

Comment: Hi David. I'm glad to report that everything went smoothly and I was able to successfully restore the production database in the test server. Thank you very much for your help. You are life saver!